# Conditional math symbols

Tags: math-mode, conditionals, ocg

In my private notes, I use non-standard mathematical symbols: I like using 0 to denote the empty set.  Quite reasonably, my advisor does not like this if I do this in my paper.  So I'd like to use 0 for my version of the paper and `\emptyset`  for his (and everybody else's) version.

Ideally, I can have only a single version of the LaTeX source, which produce the two different versions of the paper.  Even better, it produces a single PDF file, which shows 0 in my environment and the result of  `\emptyset` in his.  (I use Debian, and he uses Mac OS for our workstations.)

Is any of these possible?  There seem to be several problems to be solved here - to account for the difference in the sizes of the two symbols, and actually implementing the conditional.

Comment: The whole point of PDF is to be portable: to look the same on different platforms.  Just use \emptyset (you can always redefine it later).  Besides, if everyone used different symbols, communication would be impossible.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: If you write `0` to denote the empty set, which symbol do you use to denote the number zero?

Comment: Add `\renewcommand{\emptyset}{0}` in the preamble of your version.

Comment: @Mico According to several authors, the *number* zero and the empty set are precisely the same thing. On the other hand, the *symbol* 0 is used in several different instances.

Comment: @Mico I'd also remark that “the natural number zero” and the empty set *may* be considered the same thing; however, going up in the number sets, it is questionable whether the “real number zero” is the same as the natural number zero (it depends on a large number of definitions). So a book on set theory can almost safely use zero for both concepts, but I'd be wary of doing that in a book on analysis.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for this little guest lecture! I, for one, really appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elder people, amongst which are many professors and I, tend to prefer reading documents which are printed out on paper. So you may create a document which prints out differently than it looks like in the PDF viewer (provided a standards-compliant viewer such as AR is used, which is very likely to happen for this group of persons):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ocgx2}

\newcommand\0{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
   \begin{ocg}[printocg=never, showingui=never]{for me}{forMe}{on}
     0
   \end{ocg}%
  }%
  \begin{ocg}[printocg=always, showingui=never]{for print}{forPrint}{off}
    \emptyset
  \end{ocg}%
}

\begin{document}

Is $\0=0$?

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can redefine the way `\emptyset` is set in your version/your machine, but leave it to match its original definition in his version/his machine. To do so, I assume you'll only share your `.tex` source (and perhaps some images). However, keep a special file in your working folder called `emptysetaszero.tex` that has the following contents

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\emptyset}{0}}% Your new definition for \emptyset
```

Now, in your paper, add

```
\InputIfFileExists{}{emptysetaszero}% Update the way \emptyset is represented
```

If the file exists - on your machine - `emptysetaszero.tex` will be input, which redefines the way `\emptyset` is displayed. If the file does not exist - on his machine - nothing will happen. One source, two differing outcomes, as long as `emptysetaszero.tex` is not shared.

We delay the redefinition of `\emptyset` to `\AtBeginDocument`, in case other things (packages) might redefine it as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would define a new boolean, such as `\newif\ifUnofficial`, and then use this as a switch to give different definitions according to your tastes. This said, I'd recommend using standard notation:)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifUnofficial
\Unofficialtrue   % mine versions
%\Unofficialfalse % the rest of the world

\ifUnofficial
  \newcommand\0{0}
\else
  \newcommand\0{\emptyset}
\fi
\begin{document}

Is $\0=0$?

\end{document}
```